# how to use two dimensional array concept for retrieving the data from the selected rectangle in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, svg

I want to retrieve the data from the selected rectangle.I am having number of rectangles.If i am selecting the particular rectangle that data of the particular rectangle will be shown.I have stored the data of the rectangles in one array collection.But i dont know how to retrieve the data.Because if i am removing the one rectangle among 3 rectangles array collection indices changed.

For example,I am having two rectangles.data of the rectangles stored in one array collection.
Like this.

```
this.model.rectCollection[this.rectIndex]=this.model.selectedData;
```

here rectIndex changed for every rectangle.

My problem is, i am removing first rectangle using this code.

```
if(this.rectRemovedIndex>-1){
this.model.rectCollection.splice(this.rectRemovedIndex,1);
}
```

now rectcollection indices changed.data of the second rectangle stored in rectCollection[0].

I want to drag the second rectangle means,that corresponding rectIndex is 1.
so that selected data push into rectCollection[1].Index added for second one.but the rectCollection[0] only modified for the second one also.

```
if (this.dragdrop || this.rectPan) {                
                this.model.rectCollection[this.rectIndex] = 0;
               this.model.rectCollection[this.rectIndex] = this.model.selectedData;            
        }
```

here,the rectIndex should be 1.so data changed.

how to do.

Comment: maybe you do not update `this.rectIndex` when splicing.

Comment: rectIndex value will be the same for corresponding rect.that will not changed.because while removing the rect only indices changed.If i am not removing but i will do drag means,that rectIndex value is for corresponding rect.any other solutions possible?

Comment: anyone suggest me.that should be great help for me.

Comment: maybe some concrete data will help to solve the problem.